# Cloning Git repository from GitHub organization using Git Bash

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I'm trying to clone a Git repository using the command:

```
git clone $repositoryPath $localClonePath
```

Now I login with the organization account on the pop window, it now pops up with an error:

> You cannot use this account for this purpose because it belongs to an organization. Please choose a different account or sign up for a new one.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think that Github's organization accounts are intended to prevent commits using them. I believe the intention is that you instead add a user to that organization, then you commit using that user.

Comment: so how is this related to cloning ? do you mean I cannot clone from git bash for organization account ?

Comment: Generally, unless repository read-access requires authentication, anyone can clone without an account. Otherwise, you can only clone with permitted accounts that are in that organization. Generally, cloning is seen as a developer action, so that's likely why you can't do it with an organizational account.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @Himself12794's comments ([1](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39832412/cloning-git-repository-using-git-bash#comment66954283_39832412) and [2](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39832412/cloning-git-repository-using-git-bash#comment66958808_39832412)), you can't clone directly from an organization account. The error you got gives you a hint as to what to do:

> You cannot use this account for this purpose because it belongs to an organization. Please **choose a different account** or sign up for a new one.

[Emphasis added.]

When you are prompted for credentials during `git clone`, rather than login as the organization, use your *user account*, one that has access to the organization. (I assume you already have such an account, but if not, you'll need to create a new one and add it to the organization.)